# Management ignoring wasps/hornets in the office

Tags: working-conditions

EDIT: I work at a non-profit organization where we own the building and we have a problem of wasps/hornets getting into my office, that may spread to other offices. Our facilities manager is responsible for this problem but has not taken care of it due to cost/complications reaching the nest. We have no HR person/department. Wasps/hornets getting in our office regularly seems like a safety concern. The three of us in my office are not allergic but someone two offices down the hall is, and so is another person downstairs. On days when the problem is particularly bad (4 or more a day, as compared to 1-3 typical) my manager will have me move to a public space in our building.

I want to have a safe and stable work environment for myself and my co-workers without being unreasonable.

Is this a legitimate workplace concern to have? Should I just make the case for myself to move offices/work from home, or for my co-workers as well?

EDIT: I am not looking for how to deal with the pests. I am looking for how to deal with the facilities manager who isn't taking care of the problem, and my manager who has me relocate to public spaces in the building on days the problem is worse. I am a young professional trying to figure out what are valid complaints and what are the best ways to talk to managers about them.

Comment: Can you not just patch the holes they gain access through? Gum, tape, spitwads, silicone, glue, etc etc etc

Comment: We are not sure where they are getting in. We have tried taping the lower portions of the window. We have 10 ft ceilings, with space above the drop down ceiling tiles.

Comment: So in reality, there could be a larger problem, as in a nest in your ceiling or elsewhere? In which case the cold weather will have zero effect on your culprits. Without knowledge of either the source, or the entry access point, that really only leaves one route....fumigation. Personally, I would just let building management know that if they aren't willing to  confront the issue, then on Friday night I'd be setting off a "bug bomb" fogger so it's cleared out and safe again by Monday... but that's me.

Comment: If the cost of having pest control in is too much for them, I can't wait to see what they think of the settlement after someone gets sent to the hospital from a wasp sting that they could have prevented.

Comment: Does your company own or rent the building? If they rent, then your company - and the others in the building - should be pestering the building management company to take care of it.

Comment: Case in point: Management typically won't cash in for a fire-insurance program until the building across the street burns down. If someone threatened a lawsuit for an unsafe work environment, I'm sure it would be dealt with swiftly.

Comment: @ChrisW. While I agree that the cold weather could probably have no effect, a personal bug bomb could be a bad idea too, especially if your co-workers are not all notified. How fast is the indoor air replaced? Who might come to work on a weekend? How does it affect someone who is pregnant? (What about the office goldfish?)

Comment: @thursdaysgeek those types of concerns would be assumed as obviously considered.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a pest problem which is not unique to the workplace.

Comment: Seal the insulation holes with duct tape. Every home/office should have duct tape, WD40, baking soda and a couple of Leatherman-type multi-function knives plus spare cell phone chargers.

Comment: Splatting wasps is a very bad idea as they can release pheremones that attract other wasps when you do that.
If there're only a few you can trap them in a wide necked bottle with a screw cap. More can be dealt with using a wasp trap with a sugary substance. (Of course the best way to deal with them is still to stop them getting in in the first place)

Comment: @JimG: It's about dealing with workplace managers who ignore the problem.

Comment: see [help/on-topic] -> [Questions that focus on ranting about problems rather than trying to solve them](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696/168) "Rather than explaining why your situation is terrible, or why your boss/coworker makes you unhappy, explain what you want to do to make it better..."

Comment: Sorry it came out as ranting. I have reworded it, and I think it is clearer that I am asking how to deal with management to make the workplace safer for myself and others/ if this is a legitimate concern.

Comment: @JimG. its a H&S issue at work s I think it is a valid Q

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to the facilites manager that you trade offices with her/him until this is fixed. (OK that part was sarcasm but I am senior enough and well respected enough in my company that I would probably do that and there would be no retaliation for it. YMMV.) IN one job, I did actually up and leave and tell them I would be back when the problem was fixed but that was a poisonous snake so they were more sympathetic to my need to immediately leave. It sounds like basically you have a weak boss who won't stand up for his people.

It is entirely unacceptable to expect people to work in an office space with wasps. You should to point out the liability if the wasps stings your allergic co-worker and she dies is much greater than the cost of the professional. If the facilites manager does not immediately hire someone, go to HR and ask them what you can do when the work space is unliveable. Perhaps you and the allergic lady should be allowed to work from home until the problem is fixed. I can tell you I would not work in an office where I was at risk for an allergic reaction from a wasp sting. And since wasp stings are painful even if you aren't allergic, I would likely not put up with this situation as long as you have. You get 1 day to fix something like this once they start comining in the building.   Your boss should be pushing for this to be resolved too.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily develop an allergy after 1-2 stings, so this is a serious issue. However I would not use aggresive toxins because you can't know how they affect your health .. yeah sure, they are safe.

A possiblilty is to open the roof and remove the nest, relocating the wasps to another area and then sealing off everything. Otherwise you will have the problem every year.

Someone should really smash your manager like he did with the wasps. Would be interesting to see how many other manager will come flying around him. :/

Comment: Relocate? They're wasps, not honeybees.  Just smite them all.